# How to pass argument from one function to another in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have four functions right now to analyze a csv file.
The first formats the document and outputs (returns) four values.
The second and third take the four values from the first function and calculates (and returns) some other values.
The main function (fourth) needs to return the values from the second and third function.

My issue is that the main function needs to have an argument (the document name) which I need to pass to the first function (obviously) in order to format it and I don't know how to do it. I can't use the print or input functions, for testing purposes, so how can I do this?

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
def formatting():
   with open('marks.csv', 'r') as f:
   ...
   n = 30
   m = 9
   array = [...]
   tot = [...]
   return m, n, array, tot

def calculation():
   n, m, array, tot = formatting()
   ...
   mn = [...]
   mx = [...]
   av = [...]
   sd = [...]
   return mn, mx, av, sd

def cor():
   n, m, array, tot = formatting()
   ...
   rs = [...]
   return rs

def main():
   mn, mx, av, sd = calculation()
   rs = cor()
   return(mn, mx, av, sd, rs)
main()
```

But I need there to be an argument in main which is passed to the formatting function like so:

```
main(csvfile)
```

passing to formatting so that I have

```
with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
```

instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def formatting(csvfile):
   with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
   ...
   n = 30
   m = 9
   array = [...]
   tot = [...]
   return m, n, array, tot

def calculation(csvfile):
   n, m, array, tot = formatting(csvfile)
   ...
   mn = [...]
   mx = [...]
   av = [...]
   sd = [...]
   return mn, mx, av, sd

def cor(csvfile):
   n, m, array, tot = formatting(csvfile)
   ...
   rs = [...]
   return rs

def main(csvfile):
   mn, mx, av, sd = calculation(csvfile)
   rs = cor(csvfile)
   return(mn, mx, av, sd, rs)

main('marks.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you! This edit works to get the desired output but I now have an error when I try to run the script. It's obviously because I haven't put the argument in yet (the error says 'csvfile' is not defined), but then when my next line is main("marks.csv") it outputs correctly. I can just ignore the warning, right? I'm assuming there's just some interactivity error with running a script when there's a required positional argument.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to remove the call to main at the end, I'm an idiot.

Comment: You’re right, I’ve meant to comment out csvfile inside main to say that you should replace it with your file name.